# example of way the comments feature isn't enough

Tags: feature-request, comments

in this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5443/water-level-gets-lower-and-lower-in-toilet/5448#5448) @B Mitch wanted to add information to my answer, but because he needed a numbered list he actually had to give another answer. 
can we do something about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He could always suggest an edit (any user can do this now) which will then be approved (or rejected) by higher rep users.

Comment: and what about links within the comments? why isn't this possible?

Comment: @Asaf - if you can comment you can add a link either raw or via `[text](url)`.

Comment: Thanks. i didn't knew this. Where all of this info is listed?

Comment: @Asaf : it's in the [MarkDown standard](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Comment: @asaf click the 'help' link under the "add comment" button to expand the comment help. Comment help is pre-expanded for new users as well.